# Is it possible to swap all key values as pairs in the whole unordered_multimap in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, key, unordered-multimap

I have an unordered_multimap with pairs as keys. I would like to swap the values in the pairs, in the whole map.
Example: 
{pair<1,2>, 3} -> {pair<2,1>, 3}

I would like to iterate over the container and change all the keys. Duplicates can occur so that is why used multimap. 
Is this possible in c++11?

Comment: You can't change keys, so the easiest way probably is to make a new map.

Comment: Is it possible to erase values and then insert values with swapped pairs? However, I think that I won't be able to determine when to stop.

Comment: Yes, but then you would have to figure out a way to prevent a pair from being swapped twice.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought.

Comment: I will create a new map and then use std::unordered_map::swap function which has constant time complexity. This may do the trick. Thank you for your response.